# modeling many to many unary relationship and 1:M unary relationship

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, erd

Im getting back into database design and i realize that I have huge gaps in my knowledge.

I have a table that contains categories. Each category can have many subcategories and each subcategory can belong to many super-categories.

I want to create a folder with a category name which will contain all the subcategories folders. (visual object like windows folders) 
So i need to preform quick searches of the subcategories.

I wonder what are the benefits of using 1:M or M:N relationship in this case?
And how to implement each design?

I have create a ERD model which is a 1:M unary relationship. (the diagram also contains an expense table which stores all the expense values but is irrelevant in this case)

[image: 1:M unary relationship]

is this design correct?

will many to many unary relationship allow for faster searches of super-categories and is the best design by default?

**I would prefer an answer which contains an ERD**

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is a "1:M unary relationship"?  I use the term "unary" for "1:1" relationship (or, perhaps, "0-1:0-1" in some cases).

Comment: In Database Systems - Design, Implementation, and Management (9th Edition) A unary M:N relationship is explained by giving an example of courses: The M:N recursive relationship might be more familiar in a school environment. For instance, note how the M:N
“COURSE requires COURSE” relationship illustrated in Figure 4.17 is implemented in Figure 4.21. In this example,
MATH-243 is a prerequisite to QM-261 and QM-362, while both MATH-243 and QM-261 are prerequisites to
QM-362

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, a single sub-category can have at most one (direct) super-category, in which case you don't need a separate table. Something like this should be enough:

[image]

Obviously, you'd need a recursive query to get the sub-categories from all levels, but it should be fairly efficient provided you put an index on PARENT_ID.

Going in the opposite direction (and getting all ancestors) would also require a recursive query. Since this would entail searching on PK (which is automatically indexed), this should be reasonably efficient as well.

For some more ideas and different performance tradeoffs, take a look at [this slide-show](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Comment: Alright awesome so there is no need to panic. I was reading a book and I saw all sorts of diagrams and I didnt remember them at all so I jumped to conclusions. Thank you for your answer and the link :)

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the easiest way to maintain a multilevel hierarchy in a relational database is the [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), sometimes also called "modified preorder tree traversal" (MPTT).

Basically the tree nodes store not only the parent id but also the ids of the left-most and right-most leaf:

```
spending_category
-----------------
parent_id    int
left_id      int
right_id     int
name        char
```

The major benefit from doing this is that now you are able to get an entire subtree of a node with a single query: the ids of subtree nodes are between left_id and right_id. There are many variations; others store the depth of the node in addition to or instead of the parent node id.

A drawback is that left_id and right_id have to be updated when nodes are inserted or deleted, which means this approach is useful only for trees of moderate size.

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) and the [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) mentioned by Branko explains the technique better than I can. Also check out [this list of resources](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/links/#hierarchical) if you want to know more about different ways of storing hierarchical data in a relational database.

Comment: very interesting. I will read into it just seems like a lot of work to maintain when you insert new values.